# REST Framework writing custom fields validation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to add a custom fields validation on the serializers that will only show a specific field in the views depending on the condition stated. e.g from the model below there is a visit class that accounts for patient visits. Depending on the following statuses below,one will only view certain specific fields e.g suppose a patient arrives, one should only see the `visit_start_date`, the `status_time` will be recorded etc.

```
  STATUSES=('
    ('ARRIVED','Arrived'),
    ('CHECKED_IN','Checked In'),
    ('IN_ROOM','In Room'),
    ('CANCELLED','Cancelled'),
    ('COMPLETE','Complete')
```

)

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='rel_visits')
    discharge_notes = models.TextField(
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    discharged = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    admitted = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    current = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    status_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.ChoiceField(max_length=20,choices=STATUSES)
    visit_start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    visit_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    session_start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    session_end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    check_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    check_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is how the complete form looks like :
[image]

Comment: That’s what the `clean()` methods are for. After validating individual fields, you can add validation to test conditions on multiple fields in the `clean()` method

Answer (score 0):

In your visit model patient is an auth_user_model(Django user) so you can add permission in patient(auth_user_model),

```
1)create custom permission of auth user then
2)create a group called patient, add custom permission on this group.
```

then write a query in `views.py` according to permission.